# Unable to find gif image by Xpath/classname/cssSelector using selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to locate image using Selenium webdriver but unable to locate it by Xpath/cssSelector

I have tried cssSelector and xpath but not working.

```
<img alt="" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content" decoding="async" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/303052068860032968">
```

By cssSelector -->

```
WebElement elementOut = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".i-amphtml-fill-content.i-amphtml-replaced-content"));
```

By Xpath -->

```
WebElement elementOut = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='aw0']/amp-img/img"));
```

I need to locate the image.

Snapshot of the page source:

[image: Detailed page source]

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code of the page where your image is located ? Otherwise, it will be impossible to help you on this.

Comment: HTML Code : - <img alt="" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content" decoding="async" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/303052068860032968">

Comment: This is only the `<img>` tag. This is not enough to locate the image. What you need to provide is the HTML code of the entire page, or at least all the HTML tags enclosing the image. Also, please add that code inside your original post (you should be able to edit it, rather than in a comment). This will make it more readable, and people will be able to help you more easily.

Comment: Added link for detailed page source

Comment: You need to select the `iframe` first!

Answer (score 1):

Your image resides within an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

[image]

So you will need to execute [driver.switchTo()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo--) function prior to attempting to locate element which is inside the iframe.

Once done you should be able to use the [XPath expression](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727) like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@class,'replaced-content')]"));
```

Comment: As suggested i have switched to iframe and tried to locate the element but still i am unable to locate the element. My code as below:
driver.switchTo().frame("google_ads_iframe_/8900/24.com/Web/News24/Homepage_20");driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);WebElement elementOut = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'DfaVisibilityIdentifier_3594674463')]"));

Comment: They have updated code so my xpath changed from previous version of code.

Comment: Image code : <img src="https://s0.2mdn.net/6075616/05032019-034107749-278x100_MostRead_Save_Win_Polo.gif" alt="Advertisement" border="0" width="278" height="100" style="" xpath="1">

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the image, as the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - `cssSelector`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[id$='com/Web/News24/Homepage_20'][name^='google_ads_iframe_'][title='3rd party ad content']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("img.i-amphtml-fill-content.i-amphtml-replaced-content[src^='https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad']"))).click()
    ```
  - `xpath`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'com/Web/News24/Homepage_20') and starts-with(@name, 'google_ads_iframe_')][@title='3rd party ad content']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//img[@class='i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content' and starts-with(@src, 'https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad')]"))).click();
    ```